# Filter posts and custom taxonomy using add_rewrite_rule

Tags: custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I want to add a custom permalink structure, and based on that, use a specific template for displaying posts:

For example I have:

> **category=football**
>
> **category=baseball**

And a custom taxonomy:

> **channel=news**
>
> **channel=images**
>
> **channel=videos**

I can view posts:

> **/category/football**
>
> **/category/baseball**

and:

> **/channel/news**
>
> **/channel/images**
>
> **/channel/videos**

Now I want display filtered posts on:

> **/mixed/football-news**
>
> **/mixed/football-images**
>
> **/mixed/football-images-videos**
>
> **/mixed/football-news-videos**
>
> **/mixed/baseball-news**
>
> **/mixed/baseball-images**

and so on...

Here is the code I'm using:

```
function add_mixed(){
    //mixed.php is my desired template
    //TODO do it the right way
    add_rewrite_rule('^mixed/([a-z]+)/?', 'mixed.php', 'top');
    add_permastruct('mixed', '/%mixed%/', array('paged'=>true,'walk_dirs'=>false));


    //TODO split slug on '-' for filtering $cat & $channels

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'channel',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $channels
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $cat
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 18
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ob_start();
    include('mixed.php');
    $data = ob_get_clean();
    return $data;
}
add_action('init','add_mixed');
```

At this point, the permalink "mixed" is not working and results in a 404 Error.

Comment: rewrite rules don't point to template files, they point to the root `index.php`, and should set the necessary query vars to result in a successful main query, you don't create the query manually yourself. have a look at the examples for [`add_rewrite_rule`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Example).

Comment: ok i understand.. but how would i achieve what i want as this kind of query is not a "successful main query".